# Как реализовать Notifications и Backend для мобильного приложения?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, уведомления, backend

Всем доброго времени суток! Мне, как разработчику неопытному, необходим совет от уже знающих и умелых представителей iOS dev.

Делаю сейчас приложение и возникла проблема с бэкэндом. Решил выбрать для облачного хранения данных - Firebase. Да, слышал о нём много негативного из-за отсутствия гибкости и компромиссов во всём и вся, но решил остановиться на нем, т.к. это самый наиболее быстрый вариант в плане реализации.

Примечание: Я больше по фронтэнду и с бэкэндом практически не знаком, в Java не умею и вообще лодырь, only-Swift кодер, хипстер и прочая срань современного dev`а.

Так вот, с сохранением и корректным отображением данных в теории проблем не должно возникнуть. Но вот, что касаемо Notifications, всё очень размыто и неясно.  Мне в проекте понадобятся уведомления по условиям и я ничего не смог накопать в интернете.

Объясню на примере:
Например, у меня есть различные предприниматели, у которых разный профиль работы, кто-то механик, кто-то сантехник, кто-то электрик. Все они из разных городов - кто-то из Лондона, кто-то из Ванкувера, кто-то из Бобруйска. И у меня есть обычные пользователи, которые заказывают различные услуги. И вот, какой то пользователь подаёт общую заявку на то, что ему нужен электрик, и этот пользователь находится в Бобруйске. И когда пользователь подал заявку, всем предпринимателям-электрикам из Бобруйска должно прийти уведомление, что появился заказ, напишите пользователю и договоритесь о условиях. Данные уведомления должны приходить даже когда приложение выключено.

Также, в дальнейшем к iOS аппке добавится ещё и Android версия. А позже будет и сайт, который будет использовать эти данные.

И вот я без понятия, как это можно грамотно реализовать. Может кто-то посоветует что-то конкретное? Реально ли это сделать на Firebase? Если да, то как? Если нет, то какие есть аналоги? Либо, если самому писать сервер, то как и что для этого нужно?

Сразу извиняюсь за мою тупость, я ещё слишком зеленый в этом деле. Дайте шанс молодому и глупому.

Comment: Лодырь, срань, тупость... вы это... поменьше вербальной агрессии, а то ведь захлебнётесь в своём же яде.

Comment: Реализовать на Functions указанный функционал вполне можно. Как -- слишком общий вопрос. Я совершенно серьёзно: может за вас всё сделать и деньги получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую посмотреть Functions в Firebase.

Если в 2 словах, это возможность писать на javascript свои триггеры, реагирующие например на добавление записи в базу данных и делающие разные действия (в том числе отправка нотификаций).

Functions: https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/?authuser=1

Примеры: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Второй вариант, если решитесь изучать backend программирование, и если у вас есть свой сервер, возможно проще будет написать в него скрипт, отправляющий нотификации. Рекомендую использовать Python и PyFCM. Логика работы например такая - при отправке заказа, мобильный клиент (после сохранения заказа в базу данных Firebase) отправляет запрос на ваш сервер, ваш сервер лезет в базу данных и проверяет есть ли мастера для такого заказа, и отправляет им уведомления.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь подробный ответ.  Firebase Cloud Functions - это то, что мне надо. Теперь главное разобраться в JS и понять как это реализовать